# Html, inserting option list separators

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add separators to php-generated list with jQuery

```
<select>
    <option value="0">all</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">other</option>
</select>
```

How to put separators after first eleent and before the last element that result is

```
<select>
    <option value="0">all</option>
    <option value="-1" disabled="disabled">------</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="-1" disabled="disabled">------</option>
    <option value="4">other</option>
</select>
```

?

Thank you

Comment: Why not do this in php while you're generating the `select`?

Answer (score 6):

```
var $ops = $('select option'), //refine selector if needed
    $sep = $('<option>', { text: '------', disabled: true, value: -1 });

$ops.first().after($sep.clone()).end()
    .last().before($sep);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hxuDa/)

### *Reference:*

- [Traversing - Filtering](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/)
- [Manipulation - DOM Insertion, Outside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/)

Comment: Thanks. `=]` (better move my personal jq core notes to somewhere that I won't lose in 24 hours to never find again as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's exactly what you need, but the `<optgroup>` tag does something like that

Answer (score 1):

Shorter code:

```
$("option[value=0]").after('<option value="-1" disabled="disabled">------</option>');
```

Comment: This is nice, I just personally dislike writing serialized HTML inside of JS. You're just missing the separator before the last option, and a refined selector to don't accidentally modify all `select` elements in the page could be of help too.